# WPF MVVM How to bind a frame to a page

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, frame

I am using C# WPF MVVM and I want to Blind  my  frame to different  pages depending on what button the User clicks on.
here is my Code:

```
          <Grid> <Frame DataContext="{Binding ReadingControlVm1}"   Source="{Binding MedievalScrollPlayer }"   NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/></Grid>
```

The problem I am having is that the  new Pages is not showing.
here is my Mv code:

```
 private async void TestingCenterCmd()
    {
        ReadingPage temPage = new ReadingPage();
        temPage.DataContext = ReadingControlVm1;

        MedievalScrollPlayer = temPage;
        await ReadingAppVm1.NewBook();

    }
```

This function is being called but the pages will not appear
I even have this :

```
  public Page MedievalScrollPlayer
   {
       get => _medievalScrollPlayer;
       set
       {
           if (_medievalScrollPlayer == value) return;
           _medievalScrollPlayer = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();

       }
   }
```

but that is getting called too
but is the page will not show up.

why is this ?

the pages does show up if I do this :

```
   <Frame DataContext="{Binding ReadingControlVm1}" Source="ReadingPage.xaml"   NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>`
```

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-and-tricks-using-contentcontrol-instead-of-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx

Comment: Andy thanks,  So I started using a ItemsControl. but I am having the same problem. How do I blind to a ItemsControl?  I keep trying but it is not showing up.

Comment: There's code in the article.